# What exactly does the Infinity Gauntlet do?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

When Thanos snapped his fingers in *Avengers: Infinity War*, half the population of the universe died. So his plan was to come to the future to snap everything dead and re-create a new universe.

When Hulk Snapped his fingers, everything Thanos destroyed came back.

But, what’s the definition of snapping with a glove that has the stones on it? Is it like “Make a wish”?

When Ironman snapped his fingers in *Avengers: Endgame* all the evil forces disappeared. So did he make a wish?

Comment: Because in the movie, they didn’t show Gamora disappearing when Iron-man snapped his finger. Because she came to the future and turned Into good from evil!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What exactly does the Infinity Gauntlet do?

### Anything you want

So yes, he did **"make a wish"**.

The Gauntlet allows one to control the combined power of the all the stones.

> Eitri: I thought if I did what he asked, they'd be safe. I made what he wanted. A device capable of harnessing the power of the stones.

The stones control the universe (in effect) and **anything is possible** if you can control them.

Comment: At a really high-cost Thanos and Hulk got really debilitated and they possibly wouldn't be able to snap again, and of course, Iron Man died...

Comment: I wouldn't say anything - the glove couldn't bring back Gamora or Black Widow. I think that has to do specifically with the soul stone bargain though.

Answer (score -2):

Snapping requires some intellectual thought as well yes.

The gauntlet can destroy or recreate entire universes. In the comics, great cosmic beings try to stop Thanos and fail. He even creates life and a lover for himself.